# Move WordPress to new domain

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for some help to move a WordPress website to a new domain. When I'm seeking on the net, I only find tutorials that use all kinds of plugins. I would like to do it the other way by using FTP and PHPmyAdmin. I have made some testing and had some problems when I imported the tables to the database at the new domain. I'm not sure I'm doing this the right way, and I would like some feedback or suggestions how I would do instead. This is how I'm trying to do.

1. I download all the WordPress files to my computer.
2. I export all the database/tables to a .sql file to my computer.
3. I import the database/tables to the new doamin from my computer with PHPmyAdmin. (This is nor working for me! I just get all kinds of error messages!)
4. I alter the PHP config file with the new user, password and then upload that file together with the rest of the files.
5. Ready !? Or have I missed something?

I guess it's not that easy. I read somewhere that before I download the WordPress files to my computer from the old domain, I should alter the name of the webbsite to the new and then do nothing with the old one!? Is this correct?

Preciate some guidelines to be able to move this Wordpress website. My boss is waiting, but I told him that I need some time for testing since this is the first time for me.

Comment: Maybe this helps : http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

1. Download a dump of the MySql database. PhpMyAdmin should be able to do this through the export function. Then import this database into the new server (again through PhpMyAdmin).
2. Copy the files from the old Wordpress to the new Wordpress installation.
3. Follow [Wordpress's official guide on changing your URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) or [Wordpress's guide to moving  your site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) (As @csanonymous mentioned in comments). This will involve editing the config file as you mentioned. There may be other steps, depending on your site setup, so follow the guide.

*It looks like, from the description, you are getting hung up on the phpMyAdmin export/import. If you are getting stuck on this, could you please post a more meaningful error message in your comments?*

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I will do some testing now and return later

Comment: Good luck with your testing. Let me know if you have any issues with this, it can be daunting to do the first time, but it really is a pretty straight forward process once you get through it.

Comment: Hi! It's working now! I think the problem was that I didn't select the database when I imported the sql file with PHP-admin. In your second step I also altered the host and password for the database of the new domain in old PHP-config file before I uploaded the files. Then I altered the URL settings in the old website. I guess I have done right since it seems like it's working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy method if you are just changing domain on the same hosting account:

Just change these two values in the wp_options section of your phpmyadmin database: "siteurl" and "home". Change the domain in them to your new domain and your new domain will start to work immediately.

Comment: I think the question makes it very clear they are *not* just switching the domain on the WP install, but actually physically moving the site to different hosting.

Comment: This worked for me - thanks.  I moved my files to a new domain on the same host and that's all I needed to get WP to work.  However, I had to refresh the permalinks - which I did by quickly saving it to a new format (numeric only), and then back to the original one I had (name only)

Answer (score 0):

I find changing the siteurl and home url never works. There are often links in post text that do not migrate, especially image resource links.
The best way to do this is in MySQL.  The standard query I use is:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SET @OLDSITE = 'http://oldsite.net';
    SET @NEWSITE = 'http://newsite.com';
    UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, @OLDSITE,@NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = replace(post_excerpt, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_links SET link_image = replace(link_image, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
    UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, @OLDSITE, @NEWSITE);
COMMIT;
```

**Make sure you do a backup first before running this!**

The whole statement is wrapped in a transaction so that you do not get a half job.  If a statement fails it can be a real pain, with some domains migrated and others not. If you do not have access to transactions, you can just remove the **START TRANSACTION** and **COMMIT** statements and do a test run first.

In theory this can break serialized data in postmeta. In practice this is easy to fix.  It might break your menus and some other structured data but this is easy to fix.

**NB:** This sql transaction is good for changing from *http* to *https* as well. You just need to add:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

To your wp-config.php.